# How to generate _id for embedded objects automatically on upsert?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following mongoose schema:

```
var Model = mongoose.model('Model', mongoose.Schema({
    author: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    rooms: [{
        _id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId},
        title: {type: String}
    }]
}));
```

I issue the following query to update or create new document with default rooms if do not exist:

```
var date = new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)).toUTCString();

this.findOneAndUpdate(author: user._id, {
     $set: {date: date},
     $setOnInsert: {rooms: [
         {title: "untitled"},
         {title: "untitled"},
       ]}
     }, {upsert: true, 'new': true});
```

As you can see from the code above I do `upsert` new document if one does't exist. But In mongodb the new document looks like the following:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "55604899f4e51ebf3e648f5a"
    },
    "author": {
        "$oid": "54eac9fd5fa02c1a1b1b2a3a"
    },
    "rooms": [
        {
            "title": "untitled"
        },
        {
            "title": "untitled"
        },        
    ],
    "__v": 0,
    "date": "Fri, 22 May 2015 21:00:00 GMT"
}
```

For nested rooms objects there are no generated `_id` as my schema describes above. So my question is how could I generate `_id` for my `rooms` objects automatically

Comment: `For nested rooms objects there are no generated _id` - They have `_id`. What exactly you are expecting to see?

Comment: Sorry I've updated the post. This was my test

Comment: I'm really confused as well. They have a generated, unique `_id` attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate the ids, use the **[ObjectId](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-Types)** Type before your update/insert as follows:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    id1 = new ObjectId,
    id2 = new ObjectId;
var date = new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)).toUTCString();

this.findOneAndUpdate(author: user._id, {
     $set: {date: date},
     $setOnInsert: {rooms: [
         {_id: id1, title: "untitled"},
         {_id: id2, title: "untitled"},
       ]}
     }, {upsert: true, 'new': true});
```

-- **EDIT** --

I didn't understand the question initially but I think what you are after is the default generation of the ids. If that's the case, then change your schema to include the default :

```
var generateObjectId = function() {
    var ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    return new ObjectId,
}
var Model = mongoose.model('Model', mongoose.Schema({
    author: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    rooms: [
        {
            _id: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                default: generateObjectId
            },
            title: {type: String}
        }
    ]
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did as you suggest but think there is internal mongoose feature to generate these. Also I've tried using `default: Object` for nested `_id` field, but it also does't work

Comment: @Erik I've updated my answer, I think you are after the default generation using a function.

Comment: Do you mean I need the following: `default: mongoose.Types.ObjectId` ?

Comment: Rather `default: function () { return new mongoose.Types.ObjectId}`